Pandas resample bi-monthly on even months
I've got the following daily data:
1983-03-30    0.001224
1983-03-31   -0.003741
1983-04-04    0.005121
1983-04-05    0.009171
1983-04-06    0.006395
1983-04-07    0.009030
1983-04-08    0.006961
1983-04-11   -0.003950
1983-04-12    0.018837
1983-04-13   -0.000324
          ...

I'd like to resample this using bimonthly frequency. So I do:
s.resample('2ME').agg('last')  # Use '2M' for older versions of Pandas

This produces the following:
1983-03-31   -0.003741
1983-05-31    0.001987
1983-07-31    0.005657
1983-09-30   -0.007843
1983-11-30   -0.005444
1984-01-31    0.003011
1984-03-31   -0.000324
1984-05-31    0.000649
1984-07-31   -0.001447
1984-09-30    0.002705

However, I'd like to group (3,4), (5,6), (7,8) etc. so I'd like a series where the timestamps are:
1983-04-30
1983-06-31
1983-08-31

To reproduce this:
index = pd.date_range(start='1983-03-28', end='1984-01-01', freq='B')
s = pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index)

How can I tell resample to group on even months? Or even better, to always take the first two when grouping rather than the first 1 as in the case above - it has grouped March by itself then April and May together rather than grouping March and April together.

Is it an option for you to just drop the first month? It's a hack and may compromise dataset quality, but your grouping will probably work on even months then if you run it on df.iloc[2:].resample('2M').agg('last')

@rma Regarding your suggested edit, 'ME' was added in 2.2. See the docs: Offset aliases

It'd help if you seeded the RNG like np.random.seed(0), that way the output is reproducible. For reference see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

The answer by @mozway is incorrect because it includes the last datapoint of the previous 2 months in the next 2 months (e.g. it will include 30-Apr in the results for 30-Jun)! The way to do it is this:
np.random.seed(0)
N=365

r = pd.Series(100+np.random.randn(N), index=pd.bdate_range(start='2000-01-01', periods=N))
r = r.pct_change().dropna()
r = r.to_frame().rename(columns={0:'r'})
r = r.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'date'})

r['odd_month'] = r['date'].dt.month % 2
r['grouping_date'] = r.apply(lambda x: x['date'] + DateOffset(months=x['odd_month']), axis=1).dt.strftime('%Y%m')
r['r'] +=1
r = r.groupby('grouping_date').agg({'date': 'last', 'r':'prod'}).set_index('date') - 1
r = r['r']

Output:
date
2024-02-29    0.001835
2024-04-30   -0.007572
2024-06-28   -0.007623
2024-08-30   -0.014359
2024-10-31    0.033280
2024-12-31   -0.027050
2025-02-28    0.011792
2025-04-30   -0.005063
2025-05-23   -0.001721
Name: r, dtype: float64


You should use closed='left':
s.resample('2M', closed='left').agg('last')

Output:
1983-04-30    2.269755
1983-06-30    0.462782
1983-08-31    0.906045
1983-10-31   -0.098453
1983-12-31    1.336528
Freq: 2M, dtype: float64

See the resample documentation:

closed {‘right’, ‘left’}, default None Which side of bin interval is
closed. The default is ‘left’ for all frequency offsets except for
‘ME’, ‘YE’, ‘QE’, ‘BME’, ‘BA’, ‘BQE’, and ‘W’ which all have a default
of ‘right’.


This is wrong - the end of the previous period is included in the next period!
